# React Hook "useState" can not set full value of array after being filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

i am trying to set value of an array after being filter as the default value of useState, here is the sample code:

```
var { studentList } = useContext(StudentListContext);
var selectedWarningStudents = flattenScoreList(studentList).filter((item) => {
    return selected.includes(item._id);
});

debugger

var [mailList, setMailList] = useState(selectedWarningStudents);
console.log('mailList', mailList);
```

this is what it printed after set debugger, as you can see, array "studentList" has 91 items, array "selectedWarningStudents" has 3 items match with 3 item in the array "selected". So nothing is unexpected here

[image: debugger]

after get the array "selectedWarningStudents" i want to set its value as default value in the useState that i set below

but when i log the console it return an array that contains only first item from array "selectedWarningStudents", here:

[image: first item only]

thank you for taking time to help me out, have a good day

Comment: Are you sure the 3 default students items.ids are the same inside the student list?

Comment: Yeah, 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are getting the `studentList` data via an async way. So, since you want to set a state instead of using a derived state, your state can't catch up. Though, in this case, I expect to see no data at all but you can try this:

```
const [mailList, setMailList] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  var selectedWarningStudents = flattenScoreList(studentList).filter((item) => {
    return selected.includes(item._id);
  });
  setMailList(selectedWarningStudents);
}, [studentList, flattenScoreList, selected]);
```

But, instead of doing this you can derive the data and use it, maybe with `React.useMemo`

```
const selectedWarningStudents = React.useMemo(
  () =>
    flattenScoreList(studentList).filter((item) => {
      return selected.includes(item._id);
    }),
  [studentList, flattenScoreList, selected]
);
```

In this case, you don't have any `mailList` state, because you are deriving the data from Context data.

By the way, I don't know where do `flattenSocreList` and `selected` come from, in any case I added them into the dependency arrays. Change it according to your needs.

Here is a working example. As you can see, there is no state in `Students` component, you don't need it. You can use `studentList` as it is or you can filter it and use this filtered data.

```js
const StudentContext = React.createContext();

const studentData = [
  { id: 1, name: "foo", dep: "aaa" },
  { id: 2, name: "bar", dep: "bbb" },
  { id: 3, name: "baz", dep: "ccc" },
  { id: 4, name: "fizz", dep: "aaa" },
  { id: 5, name: "buzz", dep: "ddd" },
];

function studentApi() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(studentData), 1000));
}

function App() {
  const [studentList, setStudentList] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    studentApi().then(setStudentList);
  }, []);

  return (
    <StudentContext.Provider value={studentList}>
      <div className="App">
        <Students />
      </div>
    </StudentContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Students() {
  const studentList = React.useContext(StudentContext);
  const filteredStudents = React.useMemo(
    () => studentList.filter((student) => student.dep === "aaa"),
    [studentList]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredStudents.map((student) => (
        <div key={student.id}>{student.name} at {student.dep}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root" />
```

Comment: thank you so much, i dont know much about React useMemo but i tried the first option you suggested with React useEffect and it worked perfectly, thank you so much and have a good day

Comment: Normally, setting the props to your local state is not a good idea. You can use them directly or derive (like you filter) and use them. There is no need for a state to use your data. So, without `useMemo` you can use them after filtering, without a state. Using `useMemo`  is just a nicer way of deriving state and avoiding unnecessary calculations if nothing changes for this component (`studentList` in your case).

Comment: how can i update the state if i want to change it in useMemo

Comment: As I tried to explain in my answer you don't need to have a state. You are already getting the data from your context, so don't bother to keep it as a local state in your component. If there is no filter need, I would say "use it as it is". Why do you need a state there? But, you have a filter and this means you want to derive some data there. You can use the filter without `useMemo` and use this filtered data in your component again. `useMemo` just prevents unnecessary filtering part. For example, somehow the parent rerenders for a different reason but the `studentList` does not change.

Comment: I've updated my answer and provided a working example.